# Excel : How to select cells with more than a number of characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Only search one column, then highlight all cells in that column with more than (a number) characters, so i change the data one by one?

Thank you.

Its phone number, thousands of them, many are typed incorrectly, at least 100, i try to find them directly without going through all of them

Comment: Does the highlight need to be of the cell, itself, or could you use an adjacent column with an IF test based on the LEN function (display something if the length is greater or blank if not).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to highlight cells which contain more than X characters, you can use `Conditional formatting` and function `LEN()`.

For example: You want to highlight all cells in column A containing more than X characters.

1. Select column A
2. Click on Conditional formatting button -> New rule
3. In dialog chose last option (something like custom formula)
4. Fill formula `=LEN(A1)>X` (X is any integer larger than 0)
5. Set format for highlighting

See Excel help for better understanding.

PS: I don't have English version of the Excel, so some names can be little different.

Comment: i tried it, nothing happened, i don't find step 4, after step 4 i clicked OK.if its column C, then =LEN(C1)>X? is C1, 2 or 3?

Comment: **Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule**; In the **New Formatting Rule dialog box**, click **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**; Under **Format values where this formula is true** write `=LEN(C1)>X` (X is your number)

Comment: [Screenshot of the conditional formatting dialog](https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/conditional-format-formulas/conditional-format-rule-formula.png) - is necessary to define format in this dialog (for example: red background...)

Comment: See [example file](http://1drv.ms/1CAS9tr)

Answer (score 6):

My intepretation of your question is that you want to edit all the cells that have more than `X` number of characters.

The easiest way to do this, is in *adjacent* column use the `LEN` function to calculate the length of characters.

Then highlight both columns and click on filter (`Data --> Filter`).  Filter the *second* column to display only rows that have numbers greater than `X`.  For Excel 2010 this option is hidden under the `Number Filters` menu.

Finally, edit the *first* column as desired.

Comment: +1 Simple & functional

Answer (score 3):

I have just done this and I think the top answer is correct but not well explained.

If you have a column (lets say "C") full of data starting at row 3, and you want all cells with more than 15 characters highlighted, select the first cell in the list and:

1. Go to conditional formatting > new rule.
2. Select "Use a formula to decide which cells to format"
3. Type: =Len(C3)>15, choose a format (colour etc.)
4. Hit "ok".

Then, select Cell C3 with right mouse click, drag down over the whole column of data and select "Fill Formatting".

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any straightforward solution, I'd do:

Calculate length of text in a new column then apply conditional formatting in the original column based on data in the new one.

Comment: Would be convenient if i could type the =LEN formula in the find&replace function and replace each cell one by one. i tried , doesn't work

Comment: do you want to replace to what? it's not specified in your question, just highlighting. I use RegEx add-in in excel enabling find and replace using regular expressions, that could be your tool.

Comment: Describing a general approach is more of a helpful hint (comment), than a solution.  Can you expand your answer to illustrate how to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer, I've tried the rest and none of them seem to work except @Naresh 's but I couldn't figure out how to mass manipulate the data after that

Answer (score 0):

As you want to "Select" those cells, here is an example ..

To find 6 or more character cells

- Press control + f (Find and replace dialog box).
- Type in Find What >>  ??????*
- Press alt + i (Find All)
- Press control + A (Select All)
- Press escape to close the dialog box
- Cells with 6 or more characters are selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a more clear answer after using some help from others above:

1. Select the first cell you want to check character count for.
2. Go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule
3. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter the below formula; adjust to your needs `=LEN(B2:M7)>450`

   - a. `B2:M7` - This value should be your range of cells that should
     have this formatting.
   - b. `450` - This value should be the
     character count amount you want it to highlight if exceeded **(>)**
     or not yet reached **(<)**

     - ex: Using `>450` - if there are 500 characters in the cell, the cell will highlight
     - ex2: Using  - if there are 400 characters in the cell, the cell will highlight
5. Select how the cell will look when conditions are met using Format button
6. Apply/Ok and this is now complete.